# Animation in viewport suddenly becomes very slow

Tags: animation, 3d-view, particles, performance

I was working on a grass animation with a wind force field.
First the animation in the 3D view was running at normal speed (~20 fps) then I adjusted a few settings like Stiffness and Bending. And now the animation is running very slow (~0.8 fps).
I loaded an old save file that worked just fine before, but even there the animation speed is now achingly slow.
Do I have to clean up or refresh something I don't know about?
Is this a known problem and is their a way to solve it?

Comment: An example file at least would be very helpful for others to see what's going on. You can upload it to [Pasteall.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/).

Comment: Blender caches things like cloth physics so that they can be played back quickly, but changing settings will invalidate this cache. The only thing to be done is to re-simulate and cache it (by playing the animation through once) or bake it (by pressing *Bake* in the cache panel). Baking will simulate and "lock" the cache and prevent it from being invalidated, but as such you won't be able to change settings.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried playing through the animation again and baking it. But even with all the frames in memory there is still no change :/ I uploaded an example file http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32947